# SED Issue on replacing

Tags: linux, sed

I have these strings:

```
2017-09-17T21:01:15,914 INFO  [01196526] :sasadm@saspw - New client connection (155885) accepted from server port 8561 for SAS token user sasadm@saspw.  Encryption level is Credentials using encryption algorithm SASPROPRIETARY.  Peer IP address and port are [::ffff:191.0.0.7]:39962 for APPNAME=/SASAuthorizationServices - Visual Data Builder 7.4.
2017-09-17T23:58:17,043 INFO  [01211539] :sastrust@saspw - New client connection (163346) accepted from server port 8561 for user sastrust@saspw. Encryption level is Credentials using encryption algorithm SASPROPRIETARY. Peer IP address and port are [::ffff:191.0.0.7]:37400 for APPNAME=Content Server 9.4.
```

I have to replace them with

```
2017-09-17T21:01:15,sasadm@saspw,LOGIN,SUCCESS,Successful Login
```

or

```
2017-09-17T23:58:17,sastrust@saspw,LOGIN,SUCCESS,Successful Login
```

This is how I did but I'm not receive the expected result:

```
sed -n '/New client connection ([0-9]*) accepted from server port [0-9]* for/{s/,.* user \(.*\)\. .*/,\1,LOGIN,SUCCESS,Successful Login/;p}'
```

This is my wrong output:

```
2017-09-17T21:01:15,sasadm@saspw.  Encryption level is Credentials using encryption algorithm SASPROPRIETARY,LOGIN,SUCCESS,Successful Login
```

Comment: why posting duplicate here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46279003/parsing-a-log-file-with-sed/46280119?noredirect=1#comment79523744_46280119

Comment: Well, that question was closed and I had another little issue trying to map the sed with all other cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attemp is very close :

```
$ sed -n '/New client connection ([0-9]*) accepted from server port [0-9]* for/{s/,.* user \(.[^.]*\)\. .*/,\1,LOGIN,SUCCESS,Successful Login/;p}' file1

2017-09-17T21:01:15,sasadm@saspw,LOGIN,SUCCESS,Successful Login
2017-09-17T23:58:17,sastrust@saspw,LOGIN,SUCCESS,Successful Login
```

The only thing that needs to be different is not to allow the pattern in `\(\)` to match more than user@host. So don't use `.*` since sed performs a greedy match = matches as much as possible. Using `.[^.]*` will mach all chars up to first found dot.